# fatal error: yara.h: file not found when installing yara, for ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

i am installing a cuckoo sandbox on my ubuntu computer. I am currently following [this guide](http://www.behindthefirewalls.com/2013/07/how-to-install-cuckoo-sandbox-on-ubuntu.html) on how to do it. So far everything was going good untill I hit.

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

it fails with the error

```
running build
running build_ext
building'yara' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread-fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -02 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIc -I/usr/local/include -I/ust/include/python2.7 -c yara-python.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_642.7/yara-python.o
yara-python.c:29:18: fatal error: yara.h: no such file or directory
```

i have installed python2.7-dev, and the libs for it. any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: May be a dumb question. But did you ensure your python is 2.7?

Comment: yes, ive installed python2.7-dev and python2.7 to make sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install libyara? I know you said you "installed all the libraries" but I am not entirely sure what you mean exactly.

https://code.google.com/p/yara-project/issues/detail?id=57

Find and download yara-1.6.tar.gz

extract it and enter the dir then  run

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: thanks, apparently i didnt run the make install which made it not work.